# Lisp function to parse paragraph into sentences separated by full stops

Tags: motion, sentences, paragraphs

Is there in Emacs an inbuilt function to separate text into sentences?

Eg.,

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
> scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
> five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
> the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
> more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
> including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

into

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry.
>
> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
> 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
> to make a type specimen book.
>
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
> electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
>
> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
> containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
> publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
> Ipsum.

Comment: Do `C-h f -sentence TAB` and see what functions are available. The common convention is that a sentence is terminated by a period, question mark, exclamation mark, with *two* spaces following.

Comment: Note that "separate text into sentences" is not possible in practice unless `sentence-end-double-space` is adhered to in the source text, or the source text is not arbitrary text (which might contain confusable `.` character usage).

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined function to do that. You can easily define one.

Or just use a keyboard macro.  Use `M-e` (`forward-sentence`) to advance past the sentence end. Then use `M-x forward-whitespace` to advance past any whitespace. Then use `C-q C-j C-q C-j` to insert two newline characters.

```
C-x (
M-e
M-x forward-whitespace
C-q C-j C-q C-j
C-x )
```

Execute the keyboard macro using `C-x e`. Use `C-u 9999` to run it 9999 times successively.

---

You can also convert the keyboard macro to a Lisp command, or code that by hand using `forward-sentence`, `forward-whitespace`, and `(insert "\n\n")`.

Comment: M-e actually moves the cursor to the end of the paragraph, it won't stop after a full stop (point). Haven't found such function yet (to move to the end of a sentence).

Comment: Is your `M-e` bound to `forward-sentence`? And you can test whether it takes point to the beginning of a paragraph, and if so back it up.

Comment: It's bound to both org-forrward-sentence and forward-sentence